# Fill NaNs in Df using groupby and rolling mean

Tags: python, dataframe, group-by, rolling-computation, fillna

I have a dataframe that looks like this

```
d = {'date': ['1999-01-01', '1999-01-02', '1999-01-03', '1999-01-04', '1999-01-05', '1999-01-06'], 'ID': [1,1,1,1,1,1], 'Value':[1,2,3,np.NaN,5,6]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data = d)


         date  ID  Value
0  1999-01-01   1      1
1  1999-01-02   1      2
2  1999-01-03   1      3
3  1999-01-04   1      NaN
4  1999-01-05   1      5
5  1999-01-06   1      6
```

I would like to fill in NaNs using a rolling mean (e.g 2) and extend that to a df with multiple IDs and dates. I tried s.th like this but it takes a very long time and fails with the error "cannot join with no overlapping index names"

```
df.groupby(['date','ID']).fillna(df.rolling(2, min_periods=1).mean().shift())
```

or

```
df.groupby(['date','ID']).fillna(df.groupby(['date','ID']).rolling(2, min_periods=1).mean().shift())
```

Answer (score 1):

IIUC, here is one way to do it
if you add expected output that will help validate this solution

```
df2=df.fillna(0).groupby('ID')['Value'].rolling(2).mean().reset_index()
df.update(df2, overwrite=False)
df
```

```
    date    ID  Value
0   1999-01-01  1   1.0
1   1999-01-02  1   2.0
2   1999-01-03  1   3.0
3   1999-01-04  1   1.5
4   1999-01-05  1   5.0
5   1999-01-06  1   6.0
```